# What is the distribution of max-min for a Gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, extreme-value

For a process N(t), where at any instance of t=T0, the distribution of N(T0) is Gaussain with mu=0:

[image]
[image]
What is the distribution of max(N(t))-min(N(t))?

From my simulation, it has some non-zero positive mean value and a waveform that looks like Gaussian but has a longer tail on the right side:
[image]

Comment: @JarleTufto that looks like an answer in itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Independence of Sample mean and Sample range of Normal Distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151096/independence-of-sample-mean-and-sample-range-of-normal-distribution)

Comment: This seems quite similar to the studentized-range distribution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_range_distribution#Special_form_for_normal_data), but I'm not quite confident enough to put this in an answer ...

Answer (score 4):

Working with the standard normal case for simplicity, [the joint density of the minimum and maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution) is
$$
f_{X_{(1)},X_{(n)}}(x_1,x_2)=\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)[\Phi(x_2)-\Phi(x_1)]^{n-2},
$$
for $x_2>x_1$.  The joint density of the linear transformation
\begin{align}
Y_1&=X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}, \\ Y_2&=X_{(n)}
\end{align}
becomes
\begin{align}
f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)
  &=f_{X_{(1)},X_{(n)}}(y_2-y_1,y_2)
\\&=\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}\phi(y_2-y_1)\phi(y_2)[\Phi(y_2)-\Phi(y_2-y_1)]^{n-2}
\end{align}
for $y_1>0$.  Hence, the marginal density of $Y_1$ is
\begin{align}
f_{Y_1}(y_1)
  &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)dy_2
\\&=\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi(y_2-y_1)\phi(y_2)[\Phi(y_2)-\Phi(y_2-y_1)]^{n-2}dy_2.
\end{align}
At least for [$n=2$ and $n=3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions) but perhaps also [for larger $n$](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/03610918008812164?needAccess=true), this integral has an analytic solution.  Resorting to numerical integrations using the R code

```
dminmax <- function(y1, n) {
  g <- function(y2) 
    dnorm(y2-y1)*dnorm(y2)*(pnorm(y2)-pnorm(y2-y1))^(n-2)
  res <- integrate(g, -Inf, Inf)
  n*(n-1)*res$value
}
dminmax <- Vectorize(dminmax)
curve(dminmax(x,5), add)
```

produces the plot

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused in places notationally if you are trying to provide a general solution or if you are treating an $n=2$ special case.