# Proving Independence of Functions of Random Variables

Tags: random-variable, measure-theory

Given two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ and two measurable functions $g$ and $h$, how do we show that $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ will also be independent?

Comment: Same question with great answers: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872/functions-of-independent-random-variables?rq=1