# Can we conclude from $\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}\E g(X)h(Y)=\E g(X) \E h(Y)$ that $X,Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, references, random-variable, independence

Well, we cannot, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subindependence  for an interesting counterexample.  But the real question is: Is there some way to strengthen the condition so that independence follows?  For example, is there some *set* of functions $g_1, \dotsc, g_n$ so that if $\E g_i(X) g_j(Y) =\E g_i(X) \E g_j(Y)$ for all $i,j$ then independence follows? And, how large must such a set of function be, infinite?

And, in addition, is there some good reference that treats this question?

Comment: have you had any luck with this? I'd love to see if there is a finite set of functions that works for any pair of RVs, and especially the justification is something other than CDF factorization

Comment: I will look into it! I doubt there are in general a finite set, but any set which is a basis of a linear set of functions should do (so for instance, if $X, Y$ both have values in $0,1,2,\dotsc,n$ then a set of $n+1$linearly independent polynomials (or other) functions should do.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503835/zero-correlation-of-all-functions-of-random-variables-implying-independence

Comment: Thanks for the link. Good discussion there

Comment: The notion of subindependence between two random variables got me musing about generalizations: https://galenseilis.github.io/posts/generalized-subindependence/

Answer (score 3):

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr F, P)$ be a probability space. By definition two random variables $X, Y :\Omega \to \mathbb R$ are independent if their $\sigma$-algebras $S_X := \sigma(X)$ and $S_Y := \sigma(Y)$ are independent, i.e. $\forall A \in S_X, B \in S_Y$ we have $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

Let $g_a(x) = I(x \leq a)$ and take $G = \{g_a : a \in \mathbb Q\}$ (thanks to @grand_chat for pointing out that $\mathbb Q$ suffices). Then we have
$$
E\left(g_a(X)g_b(Y)\right) = E(I(X \leq a)I(Y \leq b)) = E(I(X \leq a, Y \leq b)) = P(X \leq a \cap Y \leq b)
$$
and
$$
E(g_a(X))E(g_b(Y)) = P(X \leq a)P(Y \leq b).
$$

If we assume that $\forall a, b \in \mathbb Q$
$$
P(X \leq a \cap Y \leq b) = P(X \leq a)P(Y \leq b)
$$
then we can appeal to the [$\pi-\lambda$ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_system#The_.CF.80-.CE.BB_theorem) to show that
$$
P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) \hspace{5mm} \forall A \in S_X, B \in S_Y
$$
i.e. $X \perp Y$.

So unless I've made a mistake, we've at least got a countable collection of such functions and this applies to any pair of random variables defined over a common probability space.

Comment: What have you shown, actually?  Although you have defined an uncountable collection of functions, where have you demonstrated they are all needed?  It's hard to imagine such a quantity of functions would be necessary when $X$ and $Y$ each have finite sets of possible values, for instance.

Comment: @whuber i was attempting to answer the question as to whether or not there exists any such collection of functions at all. I agree that the more interesting aspect is to find a minimal such set (which i'm still working on)

Comment: You can reduce $G$ to a countable set by considering just rational $a$.

Comment: @grand_chat great point, i've updated

Answer (score 2):

This is almost Proposition 7.1.3(i) from Athreya & Lahiri 2006 *sans* some minor differences in formatting:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and let $\{X_1, \ldots, X_k \}$, $2 \leq k < \infty$ be a collection of random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.
>
> (i) Then $\{X_1, \ldots, X_k \}$ is independent iff $$\mathbb{E} \left[ \prod_{i=1}^k h_i(X_i) \right] = \prod_{i=1}^k \mathbb{E} [h_i(X_i)]$$ for all bounded Borel measurable functions $h_i: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, $i=1,\ldots,k$.
>
> Proof:
>
> If (i) holds, then taking $h_i = I_{B_i}$ with $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $i=1,2,\ldots,k$ yields the independence of $\{X_1, \ldots, X_k \}$. Conversely, if $\{X_1, \ldots, X_k \}$ are independent, then (i) holds for $h_i = I_{B_i}$ for $B_i \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $i=1,2,\ldots,k$ and hence for simple functions $\{h_1, h_2, \ldots, h_k \}$. Now (i) follows from the BCT.

BCT refers to the *bounded convergence theorem* which is given as corollary 2.3.13 of the same reference:

> Let $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$. If there exists a $0 < k < \infty$ such that $|f_n| \leq k$ a.e. $(\mu)$ and $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. $(\mu)$, then $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n\ d\mu = \int f\ d\mu$$ and $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int |f_n - f|\ d\mu = 0.$$
>
> Proof: Take $g(\omega) \equiv k$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$ in the previous corollary.

The previous corollary (Corollary 2.3.12) is *Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem*:

> If $|f_n| \leq g$ a.e. $(\mu)$ for all $n \geq 1$, $\int g\ d\mu < \infty$ and $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. $(\mu)$, then $f \in L^1 (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n\ d\mu = \int f\ d\mu$$ and $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int |f_n - f|\ d\mu = 0.$$