# calculate the ACF of $y_{t}=x_{t}x_{t-1}$

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation, covariance

I am currently working on this problem that asked me to calculate the ACF of

$Y_{t}=x_{t}x_{t-1}, x \sim IID{\left\lbrace0, \sigma^{2}\right\rbrace}$

what I've done so far is, I have proved that $E[y_{t}]=0$, so I'll take it as given in the following calculation.

here I am calculating the ACF of $y_{t}$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
COV(y_{t+h}, y_{t}) &= E[(y_{t+h} - E[y_{t+h}])(y_{t} - E[y_{t})]\\
&= E[y_{t+h}y_{t}]\\
&= E[x_{t+h}x_{t+h-1}x_{t}x_{t-1}]\\
\end{aligned}
$$

given $x \sim IID{\left\lbrace0, \sigma^{2}\right\rbrace}$, therefore we can separate the expectation above into:
$$
E[x_{t+h}x_{t+h-1}x_{t}x_{t-1}] = E[x_{t+h}]E[x_{t+h-1}]E[x_{t}]E[x_{t-1}] \qquad(1)
$$

if $h \neq 0$, then $(1)=0$ because we have $E[x_{t}]=0$

if $h = 0$, then (1) is

$$
E[x_{t}]E[x_{t-1}]E[x_{t}]E[x_{t-1}] = 0
$$

which we could then conclude that ACF of $y_{t}$ is 0.

it all looks correct me but the solution gives different answer when $h =0$, could anyone spot what I've done wrong?

thanks!

EDIT:

given the comments, there's one thing I've done wrong above; when $h = 0$,  the independence cannot be applied because two or more indices are the same. this implies dependence (I think)

I therefore did,

$$
\begin{aligned}
E[x_{t+h}x_{t+h-1}x_{t}x_{t-1}] &= E[x_{t}x_{t-1}x_{t}x_{t-1}]\\
&= E[x_{t}^{2}x_{t-1}^{2}] \qquad (2)
\end{aligned}
$$

I am stuck again because I don't know how to prove 
$$
(2) = E[x_{t}^{2}]E[x_{t-1}^{2}]\qquad (3)
$$

one more hint, I could solve it!

Comment: The independence you used in (1) depends on which value $h$ takes

Comment: @Taylor I guess you meant when h = 0, we can't separate it like we have done when $h \neq 0$ right?

Comment: this looks like a home work

Comment: @Aksakal  I have done the work and checked against solution which baffles me. probably some hint could help understand what I've done wrong?

Comment: (1) is incorrect when two or more of the indexes $\{t+h,t+h-1,t,t-1\}$ coincide.

Comment: Haven't you assumed $x_t$ and $x_{t-1}$ are independent?  That implies any functions of them (separately) are independent, too: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872.

Comment: @whuber thanks very much for the link, that is exactly the question that I have, i remember that is the case, but I couldn't recall how to prove it. now I know the answer!

Comment: Thank you for confirming that.  I'll close this question as a duplicate.  That means your question will remain available for searching and reading, but viewers will be given a link to the other one for the answer.