# Deriving stochastic independence of vector valued Random variables

Tags: independence

Let $(X_{n}), n= 1,...4$ independent real valued random variables. Are $(X_1,X_2)$ and $(X_3,X_4)$ independent? If so please prove why.

Comment: You cannot prove this with the information given.  Are you also assuming the $(\mathbf{X}_n)$ are independent where $\mathbf{X}_n = (X_{n,1}, \ldots, X_{n,r})$?  If that's the case, your question is asked and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872.  If it's not the case, then what are you assuming?

Comment: no i do not assume this.

Comment: are you sure that this cannot be proven with the information given? also not if $X_i$ are Unif(0,1) distributed?

Comment: How could you possibly conclude that a set of variables is independent if you know absolutely nothing about them?

Comment: Aaah One knows what that $X_{n,j} $ are Independent

Comment: OK: in that case your question is answered already.

Comment: The question i have is the following: Why are $X_n=(X_{n,1}, ... X_{n,r})$  independent? How does this follow from the answer on the other post?

Comment: It may be that the multiple subscripting is creating ambiguities.  As I read your question, it appears to ask whether measurable functions of independent random variables are independent.  That's what is asked and answered in the apparent duplicate.  It that's not what you're trying to ask, then consider editing your question to clarify how it differs from that one.

Comment: i simplified the question

Comment: Thank you: it's much clearer.  The other thread answers it.

Comment: i really dont see how the other thread answers the question or can $(X_1,X_2) $ be interpreted as the composition of functions $X_1, X_2$?

Comment: It seems to me that I am making an incredible stupid mistake, can you please just complete: $P((X_1,X_2) \in A_1 \cap (X_3,X_4) \in A_2) = .... = P((X_1,X_2) \in A_1) \times P((X_3,X_4) \in A_2)$

Comment: I dont see why $(X_1,X_2)^{-1}(A_1)$ and  $(X_3,X_4)^{-1}(A_2)$ should be contained in the sigma algebras generated bx $X_i, i = 1...4$