# Does independence between random variables imply independence between related events?

Tags: random-variable, independence

Say I have two random variables X1 and X2 and that they are independent. Am I guaranteed that the events "X1 is less than x1" and "X2 is less than x2" are independent?

If not, under which conditions is this the case? Or better, what is a sufficient condition for having independence between those two events?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872/functions-of-independent-random-variables/94876#94876 *inter alia.*

Answer (score 2):

I remember that the definition of two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent is for any event generated by random variables $X_1$ and event generated by $X_2$ are independent. So events $(X_1<x_1)$ and  $(X_2<x_2)$ are independent is the condition that two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

Maybe you need to check the textbook or search the internet to find the definition of independent of two random variables.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* random variables, then it is *always* the case that the events $A = \{X \leq a\}$ and $B = \{Y \leq b\}$ are independent events.  Specifically, one of the (equivalent) definitions of independence of two random variables is that the *joint* CDF factors into the product of the individual (a.k.a. marginal) CDFs. That is, we are insisting that independence of $X$ and $Y$ means that
$$F_{X,Y}(a,b)  = F_X(a)F_Y(b)~\text{for all real numbers}~a~\text{and}~b\tag{*}$$
But, $$F_{X,Y}(a,b)
\stackrel{\Delta}{=} P\left(\{X \leq a, Y \leq b\}\right) = P\left(\{X\leq a\}\cap \{Y \leq b\}\right) = P(A\cap B)$$
while $$F_{X}(a)
\stackrel{\Delta}{=} P\left(\{X \leq a\}\right) =  P(A), \quad F_{X}(b)
\stackrel{\Delta}{=} P\left(\{Y \leq b\}\right) = P(B)$$
and so $(*)$ is saying that
$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B),$$
that is, $A$ and $B$ are independent events.