# If $Y$ is independent of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$, does it indicate $Y$ is also independent of $X_{1}+X_{2}$?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, independence

We know that $Y$ is independent of a vector $X$ means it's independent of all linear combinations of components of $X$. Then I'm curious about the correctness of the following statement:

If $Y$ is independent of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$, $Y$ is also independent of $X_{1}+X_{2}$.

If this is true, does it mean if we know $Y$ is independent marginally of all components of $X$, then we'll come to $Y$ is independent of $X$?

Comment: It depends on whether you read "$Y$ is independent of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$" as (a) "$Y$ is independent of $X_{1}$ and $Y$ is independent of $X_{2}$" so *pairwise independent* rather than as (b) "$Y$ is independent of $X=(X_{1},X_{2})$" which would be *jointly independent*.  With joint independence, $Y$ would also be independent  of $X_1+X_2$

Comment: Your initial characterization of independence is misleading: instead of "means" you should state "implies."

Comment: You should state X1 is independent from X2 else trivial solutions like `X1 = -X2; Y = X1 + X2` show up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Somewhat surprisingly, this is not necessarily true. For example, consider the joint probability distribution described by the following table.

| $Y$ | $X_1$ | $X_2$ | prob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0.25 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.25 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0.25 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0.25 |

Each of the three random variables follows *marginally* a Bernoulli($0.5$) distribution, and it is very easy to confirm that $Y \perp X_1$ and $Y \perp X_2$. However, consider that the probability
$$P(Y=1, \ X_1 + X_2 = 1) = 0$$
while on the other hand
$$P(Y=1)P(X_1+X_2 = 1) = \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2} = 0.25.$$
Thus, $Y$ is **not** independent of $X_1 + X_2$.

Comment: This answer implicitly supposes "independent of $X_1$ and $X_2$" means *separately* independent of each variable.  Many readers will understand this phrase instead to be equivalent to "independent of $(X_1,X_2)$"--but in this latter sense, the conclusion *is* true, as shown at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872.  Your example is one in which $Y$ is a function of $(X_1,X_2)$ (with no random error).

Comment: @whuber, I understand your point (which is also captured in a highly upvoted comment on the question). In my opinion, the final sentence of the OPs question makes it clear that this is the intention ("marginally independent").

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the "marginally" qualifier.