# How to prove the linear combination of the sample-mean and sample-variance of normal random variables is also normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable

I know that for two random variables X and Y, they are independent if they are jointly normal and uncorrelated. If the two random variables are the sample-mean $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$, and sample variance $s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2$ of a normal sequence of iid normal random variables $x_i$, proving they are jointly normal can be done in a few different ways but I am trying to show that their linear combination is normal:

$\begin{aligned} a \bar{x}+b s^{2} &=\frac{a}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}+\frac{b}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}\right)^{2} \\ 
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \frac{a}{n} x_{i}+\frac{b}{n-1}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}\right)^{2}\right) \\ &=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{a}{n} x_{i}+\frac{b}{n-1}\left(x_{i}^{2}-2x_{i}\bar{x}+\bar{x}^{2}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{a}{n} x_{i}+\frac{b}{n-1}\left(x_i^2-2x_i\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2\right)\right)
\end{aligned}$

But now that I have some chi-squared distributions, how can I simplify this and show it's normal?

Comment: Sample variance isn’t even marginally normal (no support on $\mathbb R_{<0}$), so sample mean and sample variance cannot be jointly normal. You don’t need joint normality and uncorrelated to get independence. That is sufficient to show independence, but it is not necessary. What are you trying to prove, independence of $\bar X$ and $S^2$ for $iid$ normal random variables?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to prove. I am going off of a hint given to me saying that two RVs are independent if they are jointly normal and uncorrelated, but you are saying sample-mean and sample-variance are not jointly normal even if they are independent? So it is not biconditional and the hint may be misleading...

Comment: The hint actually is a good one, if a bit indirect.  Follow it by contemplating the correlations between the $x_i-\bar x$ and $\bar x$ (which are all jointly Normal variables) and then applying https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872.