# How to check whether Yt is covariance stationary when A and B are random variables but not constants?

Tags: time-series, stationarity

Suppose

[image]

Suppose A and B are random variables that are independent of Xt.

What are the steps to check whether {Yt} is covariance stationary?

Comment: Apply the definition.  Presumably you have tried that.  What is your definition and where do you get stuck?

Comment: @whuber I get stuck when finding the Cov(Yt, Yt+h)

Comment: @whuber I would like to know the expected value of (B,  εt). Are B and εt independent?

Comment: You need to interpret "Suppose A and B are random variables that are independent of Xt" as applying to *all* $t\in\mathbb Z.$ Thus, for any $t,$ $B$ is independent of $X_t$ and $X_{t-1},$ [which implies it is independent of $X_t - X_{t-1} = \varepsilon_t.$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872)

Comment: @whuber thanks for the great explanation. I could observe that Yt is not covariance stationary but the first difference of Yt is covariance stationary. Hope I am correct.

Comment: That sounds correct to me.  There's much to be learned from a rigorous demonstration, though.  In particular, you don't have to assume $A$ and $B$ are independent.