# Is Z a random variable of X?

Tags: random-variable, notation

Is Z a random variable of X if it is transformed from X? If Z is a random variable, and therefore a function, of X, could one denoted Z as Zₓ(x)?

Comment: I haven't come across symbols like Zₓ(x) that are used conventionally to mean $Z = f(X)$ if that is what you are implying.

Comment: Is your concern that $Z$ might not be so random if $Z$ is determined by $X?$

Comment: One would ordinarily write $Z(X)$ for the transformation.  The subscript you propose is superfluous and highly unusual.  Your initial question is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/94876/919.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Functions of Independent Random Variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872/functions-of-independent-random-variables)

Comment: thank you, guys

Answer (score 1):

Let's flip it around for clarify.

If $X$ is a random variable, then all the common transformations of $X$ are also random variables.  However, these transformations likely do not have the same distribution as $X$.  For example, if $Z = e^X$ and $X$ is normal distributed, then $Z$ is log-normally distributed (literally, $\ln(Z)$ is normal).  Other transformations have other relationships.

Note, some functions of $X$ do not give a random variable.  For example, $\frac{X}{X}$ would of course always equal 1 (when $X\neq 0$).

As for notation, you can just use $Z(X)$.  No need to the subscript.  Although, if if you have several variables to transform, e.g. $X$ and $Y$, then the subscript could be useful when you are evaluating specific values: e.g. $Z_X(4)$ vs $Z_Y(4)$.

Comment: In order to avoid constantly caveating our statements with trivial exceptions, we allow that $X/X$ is a random variable even though it is either constant or undefined.  When there's a positive chance that $X=0,$ then $X/X$ is not defined at all.  The functions of $X$ that give a random variable are the *measurable* functions and, again, any constant function is (Borel) measurable.

Comment: @Michael Where you write "when $X\neq 1$" did you mean to write "X\neq 0$" instead?

Comment: thank you, guys