# Are linear combinations of independent random variables again independent?

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, independence, moment-generating-function

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be (iid) Random variables and define $Y_n:=\sum_{j=1}^na_jX_j$ with $a_j\in \mathbb{R}$, can we then say that the $a_jX_j$ are independent aswell. Can we express the MGF than in the following way $$M_{Y_n}(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{t(a_1X_1+\ldots a_nX_n)})=\mathbb{E}(e^{ta_1X_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot e^{t a_nX_n})=M_{X_1}(a_1t)\cdot\ldots \cdot M_{X_n}(a_nt)$$

Comment: Independent of _what_?  If $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are $n$ (iid) random variables (or even just plain independent (but not necessarily identically distributed) random variables), then so are $a_1X_1, a_2X_2,\ldots, a_nX_n$ a collection of $n$ independent but not necessarily identically. distributed random variables.

Comment: @DilipSarwate They are identically independent distributed Random variables. So why are all $a_jX_j$ independent?

Comment: Independence of $X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_n$ means that the CDF $F_{X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_n}(x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ factors into $F_{X_1}(x_1)F_{X_2}(x_2)\cdots F_{X_n}(x_n)$. Since $$F_{a_iX_i}(\alpha_i)=P(a_iX_i\leq\alpha_i)=P\left(X_i\leq\frac{\alpha_i}{a_i}\right)=F_{X_i}\left(\frac{\alpha_i}{a_i}\right)$$, can you prove that the factorization of the joint CDF of the $X_i$ into the product of the  marginal CDFs of the $X_i$implies that the joint CDF of the $a_iX_i$ factors into the product of the marginal CDFs of the $a_iX_i$ which in turn implies that the $a_iX_i$  are independent random variables?

Comment: tl;dr, yes, they're independent and you can factorize the mgf. any deterministic and univariate function of mutually independent set RVs are again mutually independent. See this thread for more information: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872/functions-of-independent-random-variables

Comment: The title is a bit off from what you really intended to ask.  The "linear combination" is just a single r.v. and it is pointless to speak the independence of a single r.v.  It's better to reframe your title as "Are linear (or more specifically, scale) transformation of independent r.v.s again independent?"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes**, for the content of your question.
**and No**, for the title, in general.

**Yes:**

Your $a_1,\dots, a_n$ are just some constant numbers.  Then the independence of  $X_1,\dots, X_n$ implies that the $a_iX_i$ are also independent. In fact, for any functions $g_1,\dots, g_n$ you would find that $g_1(X_1)$, $g_2(X_2)\dots g_n(X_n)$ are independent.

From independence it follows that $E\prod g_i(X_i) = \prod E g_i(X_i)$. Your calculations are correct.

**No:**

Now look at $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i$ and $Z = \sum_{i=1}^n b_iX_i$. The linear combinations $Y$ and $Z$ of the $X_i$ are in general not independent. They are independent when $b_i=0$ for all $i$ where $a_i\neq 0$, and $a_j=0$ for all $j$ with $b_j\neq 0$.
The simplest case where this is not fulfilled is $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$: then $Y=Z$.

###### Normal distributed variables $X_i$

When the $X_i$ are normal distributed, the condition
"$a_i\neq 0 \implies b_i=0$" can be relaxed.
In that case the linear combinations $Y$ and $Z$ are independent whenever $\sum a_ib_i = 0$, i.e., when the vectors $a=(a_1,\dots, a_n)$ and $b=(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ are **orthogonal**. This is a fact that contributes to the popularity of the normal distribution for modelling. One of the consequences of this fact is, that estimates $\bar x$ for the  mean and $s^2$ for the variance of normal distributed r.v. are independent :-)

Comment: I upvoted especially for the first sentence, which directly addresses the OP's confusion. Minor quibble: the "if and only if" in *"They are independent if and only if $b_i=0$ for all $i$ where $a_i\neq 0$, and $a_j=0$ for all $j$ with $b_j\neq 0$."* is not entirely true, although close enough. And the normal distribution is not the only exception, although it's the most commonly encountered.

Comment: yes, @Stef, you are competely right, I oversimplified too much. Thank you very much for your comment, I already had a kind of bad conscience with my answer! I have sharpened the statements :-)

Answer (score 8):

If $X_1,...,X_n$ are mutually independent then $a_1 X_1,...,a_n X_n$ are also mutually independent (i.e., using scalar multiples does not get rid of independence).  However, the quantity $Y_n = \sum a_i X_i$ is typically going to be *dependent* with $X_1,...,X_n$.  This means that you can indeed express the MGF of $Y_n$ the way you write it in your post, but if you were to look at the relationship between $Y_n$ and any of the $X_i$ values, you would have to deal with the dependence between these quantities.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the answers here. If we assume that the random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots X_n$ are independent, then the CDF $F_{X_1,X_2,\ldots X_n}(x_1,x_2\ldots x_n)$ factors into $F_{X_1}(x_1)F_{X_2}(x_2)\ldots F_{X_n}(x_n)$. The CDF of $Y_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_jX_j$ is nothing but $F_{Y_n}(y_n)=F_{a_1X_1,a_2X_2,\ldots a_nX_n}(a_1x_1,a_2x_2,\ldots a_nx_n)=\mathbb{P}(a_1X_1\leq c_1,a_2X_2\leq c_2,\ldots a_nX_n\leq c_n)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq \frac{c_1}{a_1},X_2\leq \frac{c_2}{a_2},\ldots X_n\leq \frac{c_n}{a_n})=F_{X_1}(\frac{c_1}{a_1})F_{X_2}(\frac{c_2}{a_2})\ldots F_{X_n}(\frac{c_n}{a_n})$

by our assumption . So lineair combinations of random variables are random aswell.

Comment: Although this answer's idea is a good one, in its details it is incorrect because it assumes all the $a_i$ are positive.  When any $a_i\lt 0,$ division by $a_i$ *reverses* the inequality; and when $a_i=0,$ you can't divide by it at all.  The result you seek follows immediately from the far more general (yet simple) fact that [functions of independent variables remain independent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872).

Comment: Your calculations are mostly correct, but your concluding sentence *"So lineair combinations of random variables are random aswell."* is not correct. In order to make it correct your need to be very careful with the vocabulary you use.