# If $X_1, \dots, X_n$ iid, are $f(X_1), \dots, f(X_n)$, also iid?

Tags: random-variable, independence, iid

If I have independent and identically distributed random variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$, then are $f(X_1), \dots, f(X_n)$ themselves independent and identically distributed?

I think the answer is yes, and assuming $f$ is nice enough (e.g. measurable), and the result is almost immediate. But I'm just hoping for a sanity check.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94872/functions-of-independent-random-variables for the independence aspect. The fact that they're identically distributed is even easier to show.